# GSON Code for deserializing a nested JSON

Tags: gson

Hi my json is like this and I used gson for converting to Java, I created a top level class with all the attributes and another class that has a list. However the values are printed as null even though array size is correct. What am I doing wrong?

---

```
Gson json = new Gson();
ProductListResponse [] response = json.fromJson(str, ProductListResponse[].class);
```

---

```
public class ProductList {

    public String code;
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public Date lastUpdateDate;
    public String lastUpdatedBy;        

}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public class ProductListResponse {

    public ProductList plist;   

}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[
    {
        "product": {
            "code": "RA",
            "name": "Read About",
            "description": "Read About"
        }
    },
    {
        "product": {
            "code": "READ180",
            "name": "Read180",
            "description": "Read180"
        }
    },
    {
        "product": {
            "code": "RLIB",
            "name": "Read180 Library Catalog",
            "description": "Read180 Library Catalog",
            "last_udapte_date": "2010-12-07 00:00:00.0",
            "last_updated_by": "fdixon00"
        }
    },
    {
        "product": {
            "code": "EREADS",
            "name": "Read180 eReads",
            "description": "Read180 eReads"
        }
    },
    {
        "product": {
            "code": "RSKILL",
            "name": "Read180 rSkills",
            "description": "Read180 rSkills",
            "last_udapte_date": "2010-09-20 00:00:00.0",
            "last_updated_by": "fdixon00"
        }
    },
    {
        "product": {
            "code": "POOL",
            "name": "Reference Asset Pool",
            "description": "Reference Asset Pool"
        }
    },
    {
        "product": {
            "code": "SU",
            "name": "Scholastic U",
            "description": "Scholastic U"
        }
    },
    {
        "product": {
            "code": "TR8TS",
            "name": "Six Traits of Writing",
            "description": "Six Traits of Writing"
        }
    },
    {
        "product": {
            "code": "TFX",
            "name": "TrueFlix",
            "description": "TrueFlix",
            "last_udapte_date": "2012-08-20 10:47:46.0",
            "last_updated_by": "wbyler00"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just a naming chaos: In `ProductListResponse` rename `plist` to `product` and it'll work at once.

Comment: @Sri Ram: The names of the fields must match the names in JSON, that's the whole reason. In case you need or want different names, have a look at [NamingStrategy](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setFieldNamingStrategy(com.google.gson.FieldNamingStrategy). And feel free to accept my answer in case the problem is solved. :D